# How to get repo and pull all branches and checkout specific branch?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I'm trying to access an existing repo from a new laptop and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
git init
git remode add origin <myurl>
git pull (does not work)
git pull origin <branchname> works
```

However, when I do git branch, it shows me one branch (to be expected I guess) but it's called the master branch, when this should be the specified branch. How can I do this? There are 4 branches in the repo in total, I want to have access to all four branches and then checkout one of the branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access an existing repository, you'll want to use `git clone your-repo-url`. Once you do that, you can access any of your branches by using `git checkout branch-name`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it. I did not know that you need to checkout branches before having access to them/seeing them via git branch.

Comment: What you do it is not exactly checking out branches, it is getting a local clone of your remote repository in your machine.

Comment: Does this mean I won't be able to commit and push to this repo or if I do so there are some unwanted consequences? (I guess a pull request will still work, right? Though that's not how I intended to do it. I should have added to my initial question that I want to be able to commit and push to the repo just how I do it on my other machine.)